# How to remove divider line between ddrawer and the list

Tags: flutter

How to remove divider line between ddrawer and the list?

I have next code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          const DrawerHeader(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(40),
              ),
            ),
            child: Text('Settings'),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: const Text("Blue Print"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

that gives next drawer:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use container instead of drawer header widget and give decoration accordingly ,

Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
height: 100,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.blueGrey,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
bottomRight: Radius.circular(40),
)),
child: Text('Settings',).paddingSymmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for your Ui:

But one issue is bottom edge is not perfect circular but bottom Divider gone.

```
       ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
            ),
            child: DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
              child: Text('Settings'),
            ),
          ),
```

alternative solution:

[image: Output]

```
Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 200,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 20),
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            child: Text(
              'Settings',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            )),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(40),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
        title: const Text("Blue Print"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```